# Rails GEM+Railtie+ApplicationController not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

This tutorial
http://thoughtsincomputation.com/posts/coding-an-acts_as-gem-for-rails-3
does not work for Rails 3.0.5. The ApplicationController is not defined so when I call

```
ApplicationController.send(:extend, ActsAsAwesome::Hook)
```

nothing happens. Can anyone tell me why or how to fix it?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced it with ActionController::Base and it works now.